# Magento 2.4.2 - Strange problem with JS path in a multistore environment

Tags: javascript, theme, magento2.4

I have a really strange problem.
We load a JS file in `before.body.end` in a multistore setup, like this:

**\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml**

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::js/js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\templates\js\js.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
require(['jquery', 'fancybox', 'domReady!'],
    function($, fancybox, doc) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var fancyboxExample = {
            openModal: function() {
                $.fancybox.open(this.$modal);
            },
            closeModal: function() {
                $.fancybox.close(true);
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

This works perfect, but for some store views, the path is wrong when checking the console:

```
*Error message in web browser console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()*
```

The path to the JS file gets duplicated with `js/jquery.fancybox.min` for some stores:
/static/version1620396352/frontend/Vendor/Theme/sv_SE/js/jquery.fancybox.min/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js

All store views are sharing the same parent theme, where this JS include is being made. We use versioning and `version1620396352` is working as expected. If we remove `js/jquery.fancybox.min/js` from the path above in the browser, the script is loaded correctly.

**Update #1**

Content in `\app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'fancybox':'js/jquery.fancybox.min'
},
shim: {
    'fancybox': {
        deps: ['jquery'] //gives your parent dependencies name here
    }
}
};
```

**Update #2**

Error in `var/log/debug.log`

```
[2021-05-18 12:17:19] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Theme/sv_SE/js/jquery.fancybox.min/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' [] []
[2021-05-18 12:17:19] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Vendor/Theme/sv_SE/js/jquery.fancybox.min/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' [] []
```

I would really appreciate is someone could be kind and shed some light on this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the relevant requirejs-config file(s) please?

Comment: Thank you very much for your input @Ben Crook, I have now updated the post with content and path of requirejs-config.js.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping to see an obvious issue there but it appears to be ok

Comment: @Alldo, Try to move fancy box js in Magento_Theme directory and then replace paths line:
"fancybox":"Magento_Theme/js/jquery.fancybox.min".
Exact path for move fancybox js: Magento_Theme/web/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Comment: Is it possible that you have Minify JavaScript Files configured differently for certain stores?

Answer (score 1):

Include your module name in the path:

```
...
paths: {
    'fancybox': 'Vendor_Theme/js/jquery.fancybox.min'
},
...
```

An example from core code:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Cookie/view/base/requirejs-config.js#L8

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'jquery/jquery-storageapi': 'Magento_Cookie/js/jquery.storageapi.extended'
    }
};
```

Good luck!